# How to scale multiple faces without moving them towards each other?

Tags: modeling, topology

I am making a hand on this model and for fingers, I want to scale individual faces of the fingers without moving those faces.

When I try to scale them I got the following results...[image: before scaling]

[image: They Moved closer]

Instead of that effect, I want them to be scaled in place, without them moving closer.

So is there any shortcut key or other solution?

Comment: Set the pivot point to *individual origins* (you find that on the bottom bar, the 2nd one on right of the mode selection)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the pivot point to individual origins.
You find that on the bottom bar, the 2nd one on right of the mode selection.

[image]

*(Turned this into an answer from a comment by lemon, with explicit permission.)*

Note:
In order to turn the cube in the picture into something similar to the hand in yours, use "Extrude individual" on the two selected faces (or your fingers).
Then scaling them by individual pivot point has the effect I think you want to achieve.